# Custom DLX options in rabbitmq binder

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring-cloud-stream for communicating between microservices. I have the following predefined setup in the rabbit mq broker.

```
"first" -> exchange of type Topic which is bound to Queue (name="user.create",x-dead-letter-exchange="first.dlx")
"first.dlx" -> dead letter exchange of type Topic
```

and the following configuration file:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            bindings:
                consumer-input:
                  group: user.create
                  destination: first
                  contentType: application/json
                  binder: rabbit
            binders:
                rabbit:
                  type: rabbit
            rabbit:
                bindings:
                  consumer-input:
                    consumer:
                      acknowledgeMode: manual
                      declareExchange: false
                      queueNameGroupOnly: true 
                      bindQueue: false
                      deadLetterExchange: first.dlx
                      autoBindDlq: true
                      deadLetterRoutingKey: user.create.dlq
```

and when I start the application  says :

```
[AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'first.dlx' in vhost '/': received 'direct' but current is 'topic', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

because rabbit mq try to declare dlx of type "direct". Here is the link of the [repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/blob/79761444bb68b5fd19a8d127c7e065c000b47d1b/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/rabbit/provisioning/RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.java#L298).

so my question ... is there any way to tell rabbit mq to declare dlx of other type than "direct" something like property name: "deadLetterExchangeType: topic"? or not to declare dlx at all.

Any  other suggestion will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to define the DLX exchange type or prevent its declaration. Please open an [issue against the binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues).

Just allowing the type to be specified might not be enough, since it might have other incompatible arguments. We should probably add `declareDlx`, similar to `declareExchange`.